# Prove that every CFL has at least one infinite equivalence class

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

If we define the Myhill-Nerode relation on a CFL how can i prove that there is at least one infinite equivalence class?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Equivalence Classes (EC) form a partition (in this case of Σ*). So yes, there are EC's to the languages you mentioned and by the MN theorem every regular language has at least one infinite EC (i'm asking that exact question but for CFL's).

Comment: You cannot prove it since it's false. The language of palindromes over a non-unary alphabet is context-free, but [every Myhill–Nerode class is a singleton](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/33417/683).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language of palindromes over $\{0,1\}$ is context-free, but [every Myhill–Nerode class is a singleton](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/33417/683). So your claim is wrong for context-free languages (unless the alphabet is unary). In contrast, regular languages have a finite number of Myhill–Nerode classes, so at least one of them has to be infinite. The same is true for context-free languages over a unary alphabet, since all of them are regular.